# Express multer not getting req.body from react

Tags: reactjs, express, multer

I'm having issues posting the `req.body.description` from react to expres

```
<TextField
    id="outlined-name"
    label="Image Title"
    name="description"
    type="text"
    fullWidth
    style={{ borderRadius: '0px'}}
    className=""
    value={this.state.image_title}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    margin="normal"
/>
```

its supposed to fetch description, and pass it to the file upload method

```
 handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        console.log(this.state.description)
        data.append('description', this.state.description)
        data.append('ourImage',image)
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            debugger;
            this.setState({
                image_url:response.data.img_url,
                // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
            })
        });
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
        console.log(this.state.image_url);
    }
```

However description is not being pass in the result console.log  ??? so req.body is not being passed.

```
[1] { ourImage:
[1]    { fieldName: 'ourImage',
[1]      originalFilename: 'Snip20190605_1.png',
[1]      path:
[1]       '/var/folders/lc/h2ln9jk15g5bbmg8vnd8sz5c0000gn/T/_gji4JKXL8gRC4iibCAIeB5E.png',
[1]      headers:
[1]       { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="ourImage"; filename="Snip20190605_1.png"',
[1]         'content-type': 'image/png' },
[1]      size: 36607,
[1]      name: 'Snip20190605_1.png',
[1]      type: 'image/png' } }
```

**routes/images**

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import multer from 'multer';
import Image from '../models/Image'
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';
import multipart from 'connect-multiparty';
import var_dump from 'var_dump';
import dd from 'dump-die';

const multipartMiddleware = multipart();

const cloud = cloudinary.v2
const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage }); 

const params = {
    width: 250, 
    height:250, 
}

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.cloudinaryName,
    api_key: process.env.cloudinaryKey,
    api_secret: process.env.cloudinarySecret,
})


router.get('/uploads', async (req, res) =>  {
    await Image.forge().orderBy('img_url', 'DESC').fetchAll().then( (images) => {
        return res.status(200).json(images.toJSON());
    })
})


router.post('/upload',  multipartMiddleware,  upload.single('ourImage'), (req, res) => {
     if(!req.files){
         return res.status(500).send("Please upload a file");
     }
     console.log(req.files)
    cloud.uploader.upload(req.files.ourImage.path, {crop: "fill", folder: '/uploads'} ,    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        console.log(req.body) // renders empty
        console.log(result)
        const img = new Image({
            img_url:result.url,
            image_title:req.body.description 
        });
        // console.log(img);

        img.save().then( img => {
            return res.status(200).json(img);
        });

    });
});

export default router;
```

**React front end**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import Image from './Image';
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            image_url: 'http://www.conservewildlifenj.org/images/artmax_1001.jpg', 
            images: [], 
            description:'',
            upload:false,
        }
    }
    handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        console.log(this.state.description)
        data.append('description', this.state.description)
        data.append('ourImage',image)
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            debugger;
            this.setState({
                image_url:response.data.img_url,
                // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
            })
        });
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
        console.log(this.state.image_url);
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
        // console.log(this.state.description)
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        Axios.get('/images/uploads').then( (response) => {
            let img;
            Object.keys(response.data).forEach( (key) => {
                img = response.data[key].img_url
                console.log(key, img);
                this.setState({
                    images: [...this.state.images, img]
                })
            });
        })
    }
    componentDidUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.image_url !== prevState.image_url) {
          this.setState({
            images: [ this.state.image_url, ...this.state.images]
          });
        }
      }
    onUploadClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            upload: !this.state.upload
        })
    }
    render(){
        const uploader = ( 
            <ImageUploader
                withIcon={true}
                withPreview={true}
                onChange={this.handleUpload}
                singleImage={true}
                buttonText='Upload an image'
                imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                maxFileSize={5242880}
            />
        )
        return(
            <div>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} md={6} style={{ margin: '40px 0px', padding: '0px 30px'}}>
                    <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        Welcome to the Dashboard
                    </Typography>
                        <Button onClick={this.onUploadClick} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                            {/* toggle between Upload or Close
                                Will be upload by default, else if upload is clicked, close will show.
                            */}
                            {!this.state.upload ? "Upload": "Close"}
                        </Button>
                        {this.state.upload ? (
                            <div>
                             <TextField
                                 id="outlined-name"
                                 label="Image Title"
                                 name="description"
                                 type="text"
                                 fullWidth
                                 style={{ borderRadius: '0px'}}
                                 className=""
                                 value={this.state.description}
                                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 margin="normal"
                               />
                                <br></br>
                                <br></br>
                              {uploader}
                            </div>
                        ):(
                            null
                        )}
                    {this.state.images.length > 0 ? (
                        this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
                            <Grid item sm={12} md={12} key={i} style={{ margin: '30px 0px'}}>
                                 <Paper>
                                    <Image image_url={img} />    
                                </Paper>                              
                            </Grid>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <Grid item md={8}>
                                <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Grid>
                {/* Images  */}
              </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution, just pass this.state.description along with

`data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )`

```
handleUpload =  file =>  {
    const data = new FormData()
    const image = file[0]
    console.log(this.state.description)
    // data.append('ourImage', this.state.description)
    data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )
    Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        debugger;
        this.setState({
            image_url:response.data.img_url,
            // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
        })
    });
    this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
    console.log(this.state.image_url);
}
```

edit the route like this

```
router.post('/upload',  multipartMiddleware,  upload.single('ourImage'), (req, res) => {
     if(!req.files){
         return res.status(500).send("Please upload a file");
     }
     console.log(req.files)
    cloud.uploader.upload(req.files.ourImage.path, {crop: "fill", folder: '/uploads'} ,    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        console.log(result)
        const img = new Image({
            img_url:result.url,
            image_title:req.files.ourImage.name
        });
        // console.log(img);

        img.save().then( img => {
            return res.status(200).json(img);
        });

    });
});
```

If anyone has a better solution thats more easier to read, that would be appreciated, thanks.